# Check if data exist when rendering JSON template in Play! Framework/Groovy?

Tags: templates, groovy, playframework

I am taking a big JSON as input, and rendering a smaller JSON output. 
The problem is that the JSON input is not consistent, and some fields are sometimes missing.

Now I have to check for null and empty list to avoid errors during rendering, and the checks becomes repeating and long:

```
#{if _.metadata && _.metadata.genres && _.metadata.genres.size() > 0}
 "genre": ${_.metadata.genres.get(0)},
#{/if}
```

Is there a smarter way to check if an item exist or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"genre": ${_?.metadata?.genres?.get(0)},
```

Comment: Sweet, is there maybe away to return a default value instead, like "Unknown"?

Comment: @IntoTheVoid You could try: `${_?.metadata?.genres?.get(0) ?: 'Unknown'}`

Comment: Thanks, works good - had to wrap the 'Unknown' into '"Unknown"' to get the qoutes